# Module name overlapping issue in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am not sure if this is supported or not but I have a scenario where in my d.ts file I want to have the following declarations:

```
declare module final {
    export class Test {

    }
}

declare module root {
    module final {
        export class MainClass extends final.Test {

        }
    }
}
```

And the issue I having is that TypeScript "Property 'Test' does not exist on type 'typeof final'" for the `extends final.Test` part.

So we are having a module name overlapping issue, is that resolvable without the need to make the names unique?

Comment: Where do these modules exist? Are they under window?

Comment: I am working with NativeScript which has a "pattern" of declaring type definition files for the native Android/iOS libraries in a separate .d.ts file in order to remove those warnings during development, they are correctly resolved by the {N} runtimes afterwards. The code snippet above is a simplified version of such files but basically it is as you see it in a single file. The same in an .ts file is also throwing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to specify that you mean the other `final` module.
What you can do is to name your modules with different names:

```
declare module final1 {
    export class Test {}
}

declare module root {
    module final2 {
        export class MainClass extends final1.Test {}
    }
}
```

Or you can place then under a shared parent:

```
declare module myModule {
    export module final {
        export class Test {}
    }
}

declare module myModule {
    declare module root {
        module final {
            export class MainClass extends myModule.final.Test {}
        }
    }
}
```

In the browser there's already a shared parent which is the window so you can just do:

```
export class MainClass extends window.final.Test {}
```

But I'm unsure how that's done in `NativeScript`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am well aware I can use different names as stated in my questions text but wanted to see if I am not missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to add a common parent module

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `type` keyword to declare an alias for `final.Test` before declaring `module.root` like this:

```
declare module final {
    export class Test {
    }
}

// define 'finalTest' as an alias
type finalTest = final.test;

declare module root {
    module final {
        export class MainClass extends finalTest {
        }
    }
}
```